# Uncheched RadioButtonList doesn't fire SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList with some fixed element and a default selected. If I uncheck the selection with javascript, on postback the SelectedIndexChanged event is not fired.

I would expect that the SelectedIndexChanged is called because the index is changed to -1.

this is the Asp.Net code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and the jquery code

```
$('#RadioButtonList1 :radio:visible').attr('checked', false);
```

As far as I know, the stage of data collection from the submit of the form is handled by *IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData* method.

I derived a class from RadioButtonList to verify when LoadPostData is called and I noticed that when non of the radio button is selected the method is not called and the same for SelectedIndexChanged event.

it seems that if the key of RadioButtonList is not present in the Page.Request.Form.Keys array, the LoadPostData is not called.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `AutoPostBack="true"`

Example:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

According to MSDN's documentation:

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether a postback to the server
>   automatically occurs when the user
>   changes the list selection. (Inherited
>   from ListControl.)

Comment: Ok, I've tried, but the result is still the same. Pheraps the problem is not the way the postback occurs, but the way it's handled on server side.

Comment: The problem with the solution you proposed is that when deselect the radio button with javascript the postback don't occurs.